# Having an error List index out of bounds while testing contact trigger

Tags: apex, query, code-coverage, case, contact

Here is my Test class for trigger , after query for cases we get an empty list:

```
 @isTest
private class TestContacts1 {
     static testMethod void testAddNewContact(){
        Contact cont=new Contact();
        cont.FirstName='Pete';
        cont.LastName='Andrews';
        cont.Phone='23456789';
        cont.Email='ghjklhj@fghj.com';
        cont.Contact_Level__c='Primary';
        Account acc = new Account(name = 'Super Company');
        insert acc;
        cont.AccountId=acc.Id;
        insert cont; 
         
        List<Case> cs=[SELECT Id,ContactId, AccountId from Case where Id= :cont.Id ];  //here we get an empty list 
        
         
        System.assertEquals(cs[0].Priority,'High');
        System.assertEquals(cs[0].Status,'Working');
        System.assertEquals(cs[0].Origin,'New Contact');
        
        System.assertEquals(cs[0].AccountId,acc.id);
        System.assertEquals(cs[0].OwnerId,acc.OwnerId);            
        
    }
    
}
```

and here is my trigger after contact inserting:

```
trigger contactCreateTrigger on Contact (after insert) {
    List <Contact> contacts=Trigger.New;
    for(Contact c: contacts){
        Case cs=new Case();
        cs.ContactId=c.Id;        
        if(c.Account!=null){ 
            List<Account> acc=[Select Id,OwnerId from Account Where Id=:c.Id];
            cs.AccountId=acc[0].id;
            cs.OwnerId=acc[0].OwnerId;            
        }
        cs.Status='Working';
        cs.Origin='New Contact';
        switch on(c.Contact_Level__c){
            when 'Primary'{
            cs.Priority='High';
            }
            when 'Secondary'{
            cs.Priority='Medium';
            }
            when 'Tertiary'{
            cs.Priority='Low';
            }
        }
        insert cs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test class, you are trying to query a case record where you look up against a contact Id, that will never yield a result.

Instead:

```
List<Case> cs = [SELECT Id, ContactId, AccountId FROM Case WHERE Id = :cont.Id];
```

Change it to:

```
List<Case> cs = [SELECT Id, ContactId, AccountId FROM Case WHERE ContactId = :cont.Id];
```